# How to split column values into multiple columns pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

I have a df

```
Name Zone                                                    Dummy
A    BARI (BA), BARLETTA (BT), BRINDISI (BR), FOGGIA (FG)     2
B    BARI (BA), FOGGIA (FG)                                   2
C    HDEF (SE), LECCE (LE)                                    3
D    GUVA (PP)                                                3
```

I need df as

```
    Name Zone                                             Symbol            Dummy
    A    BARI , BARLETTA , BRINDISI , FOGGIA         (BA),(BT),(BR),(FG)      2
    B    BARI , FOGGIA                               (FG),(BA)                2
    C    HDEF , LECCE                                (LE),(SE)                3
    D    GUVA                                        (PP)                     3
```

Tried to split the Zone and Symbol using

```
Series.str.split()
```

but not working as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `str.replace` here:

```
df["Symbol"] = df["Zone"].str.replace(r'(?:|\s+)[A-Z]+\s+', '')
df["Zone"] = df["Zone"].str.replace(r'\s*\(.*?\)\s*', '')
```

Comment: Its not working..

Comment: yes working, how to remove duplicates..! like there is two same symbols..

Comment: That's not your original question.  You should either edit your current question or ask a new one.

Comment: ok thank u, this is sufficient for now..